# Typescript function signature that converts an array to tuple of mapped type

Tags: typescript, variadic-tuple-types

In typescript, an array can be converted to tuple by

```
type Arr = any[];
const f = < T extends Arr > (...args: [...T]): [...T] => {
  return args;
}

const a = f(1, 'a'); // a is type of [number, string].
```

We can also map type by

```
type TypeMap = {
    'n': number;
    's': string
};

const g = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(args: T): TypeMap[T] => {
    throw null;
}

const b = g('s'); //b is type of string
```

How can I combine above two requirements into one? I tried

```
const h = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(...args: [...T[]]): [...TypeMap[T][]] => {
    throw null;
}
const c = h('s', 'n');
```

However, c is type of `(string|number)[]` instead of `[string, number]`.
I tried

```
const h = <T extends (keyof TypeMap)[]>(...args: [...T]): [...TypeMap[T[number]][]] => {
    throw null;
}
```

but got the same c.

I found a solution using object instead of tuple, but tuple solution are welcome.

```
const f1 = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(...args: [...T[]]): {[P in T]: TypeMap[P]} => {
    throw null;
}
const {s, n} = f1('s', 'n');
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKBDAdiA2gXQNwBQAxgPboDOwUAZslADwAqUEAHsBOgCbmwIB8ACgB0o1HADm5AFxQso4YxwBKWfNFLk-KAG8CUA1DgRgAVzjo0k8oQC+BYmUpo61QQEYANFADkqH8qEBKCQUIzgEACyqGB0eoa+6D6y6KYAtgBGEHCECT7kyVCUcACW6BIEtkGkFFQSdEws7Jw8UADWECAktOGQ0WBC4lKyjKphEf1Ymkja8YbAABZwJADuUKkANht2DjXOGXQSgvkB1U5UCw3MbBzcvB1dPRMxQgpDMnIKjLgqal-PYCmOB+Wl0+nmS1W61MWx2ewu7iuTVurUED264z6MWUuFeYmsfw0v0+GgBUywqUy2RwwJpoLmBkWyzWm22lUctSgRDoC2OBW8PiSgV25xoiJQjRuLXunQxvSiLxE+OGJMUPzGOiwAAUoGUwjgRmStThbPTwYzISyYWz7PDdORvOhTShqO4+T4BULCEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Given `T`, a tuple type, `{[I in keyof T]: ...T[I]...}` will be another tuple type; the `I` only iterates over numeric indices of `T`.  Note that due to a bug/limitation in TypeScript (see [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995)) the compiler doesn't realize that `T[I]` will be the element type of `T`, so you have to use some trick like [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

In your case, from the input tuple `T` extending `Array<keyof TypeMap>`, you want the output tuple to have an element of type `TypeMap[T[I]]` at numeric index `I`:

```
const h = <T extends (keyof TypeMap)[]>(...args: [...T]): {
    [I in keyof T]: TypeMap[Extract<T[I], keyof TypeMap>]
} => {
    throw null;
}

const c = h('s', 'n'); // [string, number]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8oCgr6gHIA7QgLimIFcBbAIwgCcBuPAwgZ3Kg+EYEtiAcxwBfVjhwBjAPbFeUABbooAHhhQIAD2ARiAEw5QAFAGsIIGQDNY8ZGACUAbQC6APmMA6b0kZCOFE7enjAuDhSYbPhOAJJQglDmljahFHCQ9k4AojqMSFLA6rEuADSJFta2GShuLmLoblhRUMCKjDIA7pRUADY9rKLScgpSKorGnIRlJIQOzFAA9AtQTrwCwmXU9EwuuEA)